# How to add a row to a table on button click using React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I want to create a table header and add a button above the table which on click adds a new row to the table.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Go through this link for asking a better question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This would help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171107/how-to-add-and-remove-table-rows-dynamically-in-react-js

Comment: What have already tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Mayank - am looking for help on creating responsive datatables in React Native(mobile app) where I can add new rows dynamically onclick of button. As this is my first time am not able find out a proper solution.

Comment: @KaranMehta -  Thanks for the suggestion, but Am looking for help using React Native

Comment: Language used in react native is react.js only so you can use that example to build yours

Comment: Here we don't write solutions to problems from scratch, but help those who are stuck while something (coding). Update your question with packages, snippets that you have tried and some error stack-trace that you encountered while trying them

Answer (score 1):

Just see the example below

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
   const [rows,setRows] = useState([])

return (
 <div className="App">
   <h1>Header</h1>
   <div>
     {rows.map((item)=>(<div><h1>{item.number}</h1></div>))}
   </div>
  <button onClick={()=>setRows([...rows,{number:rows.length}])}>Add Row</button>
</div>
 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. but still am not able to add a new row on clicking button

Comment: @Bhargavireddy have you found any solution yet?